# Is there a hotel / B&B Finder using Google or Bing maps?

Tags: online-resources, hotels

I'm looking for a good site that lists Hotels and B&B on top of Google Maps or Bing Maps.
That has tool tips with prices and availability.

What is the best site of this kind?

Comment: I work on http://bnbstar.com project. Maybe it will be helpful

Comment: This question would also be on-topic on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) - why not try asking there too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hipmunk.com](http://hipmunk.com) is exactly what you need. It meshes Google Maps with a list of hotels. You can filter by price, amenities, hotel chains (including B&Bs). You can get heatmaps for food, tourism, shopping, nightlife, and vice.

Runner up: [Kayak.com](http://kayak.com). Similar to Hipmunk, with a more conventional list of options.

Also see these B&B and Hostel sites with map views:

- [AirBnb.com](http://airbnb.com): Vacation rentals, private rooms, and sublets by the night.
- [HostelWorld.com](http://hostelworld.com): Hostels

Answer (score 5):

[Hostelworld](http://www.hostelworld.com/) maps all available accomondations on a GoogleMap. Maybe this is something for you. It is more a online booking tool for hostels, but you can also find pension, b&b, appartments and cheap hotels.

[Ebookers](http://www.ebookers.com) also maps the available accomondations on Google Map. There you can find all kinds of hotels and even flights, cars, etc.

And another big site, [Booking.com](http://www.booking.com), lists all available accomondations on Google Map.

I think nowadays almost all more or less serious site have a functionality like this.

Comment: Besides HostelWorld, HostelBookers also has maps. They both seem to use Google Maps if I'm not mistaken but I haven't found a way to bring up the info of either site on a regular Google Map. In the part of the world I'm in (Bulgaria) both sites also list hotels but I don't think that is the case everywhere.