# Any fast internet (good wifi) in Ubud (Bali)?

Tags: internet, indonesia, wifi, bali

I am looking for a good wifi connection in Ubud (Bali, Indonesia).

I need to upload a fair amount of videos and pictures (6+ GB), and give a couple of Skype/Hangout phone calls.

I used [Wifi.id](http://wifi.id/) (in Java mostly) in the past but here I went to 2 advertised locations on their website, one I could not find at all, the next one (in a restaurant) was down for some reason.

If anybody knows a place with a decent wifi, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: There might be some information in [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/what-equipment-should-i-travel-with-to-increase-the-odds-of-good-internet-and-ph) that helps you.

Answer (score 8):

So, here I gather a few names mentioned in the web pages listed in the resources below:

- [kismetbali.com](http://www.kismetbali.com/): a cafe/restaurant/shop providing fast internet, see on the website `Finding fast internet in Ubud has been quite a challenge. We pay top dollar to provide our customers with fastest Fiber Optic available in the region. Uploads or Downloads its Ultra-Fast.
- [Coffee & ...](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurant_Review-g297701-d1943034-Reviews-Coffee_and-Ubud_Bali.html): a cafe not far from the monkey forest
- [Tutmak](http://tutmak.com/): a cafe
- Clear Cafe
- [Paradiso](http://www.paradisoubud.com/): a raw food cafe attached to Earth Cafe, located just off of Jalan Hanoman
- [hubud.org](http://www.hubud.org/): a workspace, so yes some commitment is needed (a monthly one), probably only good if sticking around for a while. [Book & see prices for Hubud](https://hubud.wildapricot.org/join/)
- and more ... listed in the resources

---

#### The 3G or LTE solution

If planning to be on the move, getting an LTE sim card or a 3G sim card is probably a good solution too. See the other answer provided for further details on LTE sim cards.

Telkomsel has the best coverage in Indonesia in my experience, but it's a bit more expensive, 255'000 IDR for 8GB of data valid 30 days on a 3G network (in 2015).

[image: Telkomsel 3G prepaid data offers]

Indosat has a poorer coverage in Indonesia in my experience, but it's cheaper (& usually works fine in cities), if I remember well the price is around 180'000 IDR for 8GB of data valid for 30 days on a 3G network (in 2015).

**Telkomsel** 3G sim card speedtest result when in Bali (Sanur):
[image: Telkomsel 3G sim card speedtest result]

Telkomsel has offers for LTE (4G) sim cards, but I think it's only coming with contracts (not prepaid), see picture below.

[image: Telkomsel 4G offer]

---

#### Resources

- [techinasia.com/coworking-spaces-in-bali-indonesia](https://www.techinasia.com/coworking-spaces-in-bali-indonesia)
- [tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294226-i7220-k8077974-Recharge_Telkomsel_simPATI_Loop_with_Flash_Data-Bali.html](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294226-i7220-k8077974-Recharge_Telkomsel_simPATI_Loop_with_Flash_Data-Bali.html)
- [nomadforum.io/t/any-fast-internet-spots-in-canggu-or-ubud-bali/1696/3](https://nomadforum.io/t/any-fast-internet-spots-in-canggu-or-ubud-bali/1696/3)
- [bali.mehthesheep.com/hunt-fast-wifi-in-ubud-bali](http://bali.mehthesheep.com/hunt-fast-wifi-in-ubud-bali/)
- [mariepoulin.com/blog/the-many-offices-of-ubud-bali](http://mariepoulin.com/blog/the-many-offices-of-ubud-bali/)
- [clarintatravels.com/4-hidden-hangout-gems-with-great-wi-fi-in-ubud-bali](http://clarintatravels.com/4-hidden-hangout-gems-with-great-wi-fi-in-ubud-bali/)
- [uprootingourlives.com/#!The-Best-and-Fastest-WiFi-in-Ubud/cmbz/54ffdaa80cf24585979e2dd5](http://www.uprootingourlives.com/#!The-Best-and-Fastest-WiFi-in-Ubud/cmbz/54ffdaa80cf24585979e2dd5)
- [slideshare.net/ryansobol/secrets-to-fast-internet-on-bali](http://slideshare.net/ryansobol/secrets-to-fast-internet-on-bali)

Comment: I had 4g cards in Bali, they were not expensive and without contract, but I never thought of purchasing a flat rate. Some co working space offer hours membership, but they are super expensive. I wonder if there is some internet point with fast connection. In Kuta area there are tons of internet points and probably they have decent connection at cheap price https://www.google.nl/maps/search/internet+point/@-8.7258146,115.1626209,14z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=it

Answer (score 6):

#### Most Wifi Upload Speeds Are Probably Less Than 5Mbps

[It looks like most terrestrial ISPs in Bali are using legacy copper](http://www.expat.or.id/info/internetaccess.html%23Providers) (ie. repurposed telephone and coaxial TV cables).  The highest upload speed you'll achieve at any single site served by legacy copper is most likely limited to 5Mbps.  The 5 Mbps upload speed limitation is inherent to most legacy copper networks because their bandwidth is rather limited and ISPs allocate much more spectrum to download than upload.  I have found a few exceptions where coax cable provided up to 15Mbps upload, but that seems to be very rare.

In my travels I have found that the vast majority of wifi hotspots are served by legacy copper (you can infer as much rather easily with the right network tools).  While I have never traveled to Bali, I don't see why the situation would be any different there.

#### How Long Will the "6Gb" Upload Take?

I assume you you need to upload 6 *gigabytes* of data (as opposed to *gigabits*).

If you were able to find a hotspot where you could use the full 5Mbps upload bandwidth, the 6 GB of data you need to upload would take about 3 hours).  That's best case scenario.  I would expect it to take 4x to 10x that long because you'll probably experience network congestion or QoS that reduces your upload speeds.  So you're looking at maybe a half GB upload per hour if you are sort of lucky.

#### Fibre Hotspots

MetroNET seems to be an ISP in Bali that uses fibre.  Fibre, in general, does not wind up with an inherent upload speed limit the way legacy copper does.  I would try to find a hotspot served by this network for there is at least a hope of achieving the upload speeds to get your images and video out.  Even if the site has a fibre connection, your connection might still be throttled so you'll still have to do some testing to be sure.

#### Ookla Speed Test is Your Friend

I generally run Ookla's speed test on any network I might need to use while traveling.  I find bandwidth to always be a struggle when traveling, so I like to know early what speed networks are available.

#### LTE

Your best bet may be a local LTE SIM card.  I regularly achieve 20 Mbps upload speeds over LTE when traveling.  That would bring your 6 GB upload down below an hour.  You'll have to be near a good cell tower and consider bandwidth caps, but it might be your only practical solution.

This solution is kind of a moving target because it depends on finding a network operator that offers reasonably-priced prepaid short-term data plans.  So far I have found that the availability of such plans for any given network operator changes from time to time (at least in North America and Europe).  I tried to determine if one of the Indonesian operators offer such a plan without success (I can't read Indonesian).

Comment: The only LTE provider in Indonesia is BOLT but their sim card can only be used with their own routers...

Comment: @NeAnDerthal [This article](https://www.techinasia.com/telkomsel-indosat-xl-axiata-bolt-4g-lte-indonesia/) implies that there are LTE providers other than BOLT.  [The Telkomsel LTE coverage map](http://internet.telkomsel.com/4g-lte/coverage_area) confirms their coverage in Denpasar.

Comment: @NeAnDerthal I'm not sure what you mean by "routers."  Do you mean that BOLT SIM cards can only be used with phones network-locked to the BOLT network?

Comment: until recent time it was only BOLT, good that they have another providers now. Regarding the routers, BOLT only provide data and their sim cards only work with their Wi-Fi modems.. I got one.

Comment: @NeAnDerthal Oh, interesting.  What upload speeds do you get with your bolt modem?

Comment: I do not remember the exact speed, but in general it was not as good as other LTE services I tried in other countries.. but for sure better than the shitty 3G over there.. Now I got cable in my place in Jakarta and it is quite stable and fast compared to both 3G and 4G.. but I do not spend much time in Jakarta so I do not complain much.. Bottom line Internet in Jakarta is bad if you compare it to other places.

Comment: @alx9r thanks for your very analytical answer, it did bring up some interesting point. Actually, since I'm moving around a lot I ended up just buying a 3G SIM card with 8GB of data and uploading all I needed over several days/nights.

Comment: @AdrienBe You're welcome.  Do you know what upload speed you experienced with your 3G SIM?

Comment: @alx9r not sure actually. I could roughly upload 150MB per hour with indosat, when it was stable as it often stopped. I just ran a test with Telkomsel on 3G with speedtest.net while in Bali (Sanur) & got the results: 2.35Mb/s for upload, & 7.95Mb/s for download

Answer (score 4):

There's really great wifi at [Outpost coworking in Ubud](http://www.outpost-asia.com) another one of my favorite spots is Bali Bohemia. Really chilled out environment although sometimes there wifi cuts out and they have aggressive monkeys all around that will potentially try to steal your food. For coworking, Outpost, best place for productivity in my opinion. Coffee shops, Bali Bohemia is nice.

Comment: Not sure if it's only me but it sounds like bad spam ...

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays there are also providers that use coax and fibre optics.
In Ubud you can get a cable internet (coax) connection through Biznet. They have packages up to 100mbps.

Please see this article for more information; http://balipedia.com/articles/how-to-get-a-good-internet-connection-in-bali