# Quality of WiFi and 3G reception in Amed (Bali)?

Tags: internet, indonesia, wifi, mobile-operators, bali

I am considering going for at least one month to Amed (to get more into free-diving). I need to be able to make Skype calls and other work-related tasks. I need a speed **equivalent** to one allowing me to watch YouTube videos. [Ubud is way more connected in comparison](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50033/any-fast-internet-good-wifi-in-ubud-bali), so I don't expect anything wonderful.

Wondering if anyone has done this before and if yes: what 3G provider they used, or what cafe/restaurant/hotel had a good/reliable enough WiFi connection?

Note that **I went to Amed last year** and the 3G connection on the two providers I used at the time was terrible.

P.S. I also posted this question on [nomadforum.io/t/quality-of-wifis-3g-reception-in-amed-bali/7310](https://nomadforum.io/t/quality-of-wifis-3g-reception-in-amed-bali/7310)

Comment: If you were there last year and the quality was terrible, why do you expect something to change this year?

Comment: @JonathanReez coz it's southeast Asia, Bali more precisely, things change fast

Comment: @AdrienBe which two providers did you use last year?

Comment: @MarkMayo Telkomsel for sure, the other one I'm not sure. I looked at the logos listed on [prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Indonesia](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Indonesia) & I think the other one was "XL Axiata"... but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

A friend who was in **Amed** (Bali, Indonesia) recently did a speed test.

Test configuration:

- Device: iPhone
- Speed test website: [bandwidthplace.com](http://www.bandwidthplace.com/)
- Date: December 2016
- Network: 3G, **Telkomsel** (using Simpati prepaid plan)

---

#### Results

- Download: 10.75Mbps
- Upload: 3.71Mbps
- Ping: 80ms

[image: Amed (Balid, Indonesia) speed test results]

---

#### Resources

[telkomsel.com/product/simpati](http://www.telkomsel.com/product/simpati)

[prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Indonesia](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Indonesia)