# What's a packing list one could use when traveling to a place with hot weather?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, weather-and-climate, packing

I'm traveling to a place with hot weather for a few weeks. What's a good packing list I could use to prepare myself and make sure I don't have to buy anything from the local stores (except food)?

Obviously only stuff specific to weather should be included, not general stuff to pack like itineraries or passports. The ideal answer should be as comprehensive as [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/13712/9009) about mobile connectivity and include subsections for different types of hot weather (desert, tropical, humid).

Comment: Define "hot'.  It can mean a lot of things as temperature is only one aspect of importance when packing.  EG I'd pack differently for the Sahara than for Barbados.

Comment: @PeterM The answer could include both options

Comment: How hot ? Hotness is relative. For some hot is above 20 and for some, like me, it starts above 40. 20 degree hot is very different from above 40 degree hot.

Comment: @DumbCoder whatever is above 25 degrees. The answer shouldn't be too long anyway. In the end this will be a series of question about packing and finally a master question which links them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desert Hot:

- Long sleeve cotton shirts (white color)
- Long cotton pants (white
  color)
- sandals

Tropical Hot:

- Short sleeve shirts (gaudy colors or prints so everyone knows you are a
  tourist)
- Short pants
- sandals

Both:

- Sunglasses
- Sunscreen
- Hat with brim
- Refillable water bottle
- Beer bottle opener (practice drinking beer with ice)

Comment: @davidricherby - happy?

Comment: I would add a fan (either a handheld folding one or a battery one) and a cooling scarf (it's filled with beads that soak up water so it stays damp for hours and really does cool you.) And those clothes should be loose-fitting to allow for air circulation. Also elastics or ribbons or something to tie back long hair. And the shorts or long pants can be replaced with a long flowy skirt, too.

Comment: @Tom No. I was looking forward to a nice treacle pudding. :-D

Comment: @DavidRicherby - why do English folks call cake with something drizzled on top "pudding"?

Comment: @Tom A treacle pudding had better have more than a drizzle! "Pudding" has been used in English to refer to cooked desserts since at least the middle of the 16th century, and for other (usually savoury) foods since the 13th century. So I'd say the real question is why do American folks use the word "pudding" to refer exclusively to set custards and blancmanges? That's a much more modern usage, and thus the one that requires explanation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Based on your explanation it seems the word has evolved over the years in its meaning, Americans have simply fine tuned that evolution one step further, whereas the Brits seem stuck in the middle ages 