# Good and stable internet in Mexico

Tags: mexico, internet, wifi

I do some work/research online for which I need fast and stable internet. I need to make video calls, download and upload data frequently, access remote servers etc. I am currently located in Tulum, Quintana Roo where I paid for a membership in a co-working space. There, the internet works perfectly, however in the near future, I would like to move to a less touristy area than Tulum. One place I am considering is Mahahual where I could not find any co-working spaces. I am open to other locations, too.

Without co-working spaces, I see three options for internet access. In a cafe with WiFi, in my accommodation or mobile data. In my experience, the first two are usually too slow and unreliable for my work. Mobile data I think depends on the network coverage and plus, I haven't been able to find any unlimited packages from any providers. Buying 5GB every day for 500 pesos is just not feasible.

So, I wonder if there is something I can do to get good internet, for example satellite internet or to install something in my accommodation in cooperation with the owner. I also saw an answer to a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80329/how-to-cope-with-too-slow-wi-fi-at-hotel) that mentions Speedify but I am not sure that can help me. I admit I don't know much about internet connection and its peculiarities. Obviously, I am aware it will cost me something and up to USD100/month would be ok.

**Question:** What can I do to have stable and fast internet outside of major cities in Mexico?

Comment: Hope they open up starlink to Mexico quickly?

Comment: Keep in mind there are still many parts of the rural US where it would be difficult to find what you are looking for.  Normal sat internet is not going to work for video calls due to lag.

Answer (score 2):

Internet access *within* cities in Mexico isn't great, you'll be lucky to find great internet outside the cities.  In my experience at least 3G mobile access has been available most places I've been, including rural Baja, but I can't speak for all of Mexico.  I imagine 3G will be too slow if you consider the wired to accommodation options too slow.

If you are in areas you know you will have acceptable mobile coverage, you could look at using a US roaming data account such as [Google Fi](https://fi.google.com/about/).

That all said, you mentioned 5GB per day - you'd be hard pressed to find even an "unlimited" provider allowing you to use 5GB per day... it'd likely fall outside of their "reasonable use" conditions.

Telmex would be the largest and broadly used wired provider, they're available in most towns (but not so much rurally).  They're often slow, but you may need to adjust your usage to suit what they provide.  I worked remotely via one of these connections for over a year (2mb/s down, 0.2 up) and coped alright - although I had to limit my family's use while I was working.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, 5GB a day is too much. I just hate buying data per GB because then I keep thinking what to download and it's distracting me. Google Fi looks interesting! So what exactly do I need to check with regard to the mobile coverage? If the area where I go has 4G?

Comment: @JanPisl I don't currently use a Mexico cellphone plan, but I think back when we did the max we could get was 13gb, with free Facebook, Messenger, and WhatsApp.  I believe if you sign up for a monthly plan (most of what you see advertised here is pre-pay or pay as you go rather than monthly accounts) you might be able to get higher allowances.

Comment: @JanPisl Yes I'm guessing you're going to want a minimum of 4G or LTE, but I don't know if I've ever seen a coverage map here.  I do find that driving out of the towns, even in northern Baja, you hit 3G fairly quick, so if you're in a town you might get coverage, but if you're even remotely rural you might be out of luck